# XQuery: How come both "() = ()" and "() eq ()" evaluate to false?

Tags: types, boolean, xquery

The following XQuery snippet:

```
let $x := ()
return if (not($x eq $x) and not($x = $x))
    then "wat"
    else "makes sense"
```

returns `wat`. Why? The [Effective Boolean Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/effective-boolean-value-xquery) of an empty sequence is supposed to be `false`, but both `false() eq false()` and `false() = false()` evaluate to `true`…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-comparisons for value comparison operators like `eq`, it says: "If an atomized operand is an empty sequence, the result of the value comparison is an empty sequence". So `() eq ()` evaluates to `()` and then `not(())` to `true()`.

Comment: Ah, indeed. And since the `=` operator on sequences is implicitly an existential operator ("there exists two elements in the sequence such as…"), it makes sense that calling it on empty sequences returns true no matter what the general operator is.