# marklogic fn:index-of unexpected results

Tags: xquery, marklogic

In MarkLogic and xquery, I need to negate looking for a collection on a document , so I tried:
`( fn:index-of(xdmp:document-get-collections($found-uri ),"/catalog/")  eq () )`
When that statement is true the record is not in the catalog.
However, executing that statement on a document not in that collection, I don't get "true"; it returns false.
`fn:index-of(xdmp:document-get-collections($found-uri ),"/catalog/")`  returns "empty sequence" in QConsole.

So when I test it for () I should get "true", right?

Comment: to be clear, the name of the collection is "/catalog/"? You aren't testing whether "/catalog/" is contained within the collection name, just whether or not there is a collection called "/catalog/"? You want a statement to return `true()` if none of the collections are equal to "/catalog/" (even if there are no collections), and `false()` if there is a collection called "/catalog/" ?

Comment: Right, the collection name is "/catalog/", and I want to know if none of the document's collections are equal to that. Having no collections at all would be equivalent to not having a collection named /catalog/.

Answer (score 0):

When you compare an empty sequence to an empty sequence: `() eq ()` it returns `false`

To test whether any of the collections are equal to "/catalog/" you could use:

```
xdmp:document-get-collections($found-uri ) = "/catalog/"
```

To negate that, use `not()`:

```
not(xdmp:document-get-collections($found-uri ) = "/catalog/")
```

The following:

```
not("no-match" = "/catalog/"),
not(("no-match", "/catalog/") = "/catalog/"),
not(() = "/catalog/")
```

Returns:

```
true,
false,
true
```

Comment: Sure, but WHY would ```() eq ()``` be ```false```, forcing me to work around that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47551767/14419

Comment: Well if it's in the spec I guess I go with it, but it seems to contradict set theory: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/987545/why-there-is-a-unique-empty-set